# Bilinaer forms-Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

[image]

Part b said to find $ tr P^{(T)} Q $ which is done

How would you do/start part c?

Comment: What is your answer to part b?

Comment: tr(P^(T)Q)=ae+cg+bf+dh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've computed $\text{tr}(P^\top Q)$, then you can mimic the same computation with $Q=P$ to get $\text{tr}(P^\top P)$. Equivalently, take your answer from part (b) and substitute $e=a$, $f=b$, $g=c$, and $h=d$.

Once you get (c), it should be clear how to answer (d). That is, setting the answer to (c) equal to zero should somehow imply $a=b=c=d=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I get that part I forgot to mention the topic is bilinear forms so wouldn't you have to come up with a bilinear form formula?

Comment: What do you mean by bilinear formula?

Comment: B(xy)=x^(t) Py for a suitable matrix P

Answer (score 0):

It is very obvious that $tr (P^{t}P) $ is the sun of squares of the elements of P i.e., $a^2 +b^2+ c^2 +d^2$. Setting this to be equal to 0 obviously implies that $a=b=c=d=0$. i.e., P is a zero matrix.